# Problem with inspect using PyInstaller; can get source of class but not function

Tags: python, pyinstaller, inspect

My first post on here, bear with me.....

I'm working on bundling a tkinter application using PyInstaller, and I've come across an issue when I use the `inspect` library.  Basically, I can call the source code of a class, but not a function, that I have written.  I've made this contrived case to demonstrate:

I have a folder structure like this:

```
experiment/
---experiment.py
---init.py
---resources/
    /---resources.py
    /---init.py
---loader/
    /---loader.py
    /---init.py
```

`resources.py` defines one function an one class:

```
def foo(a):
    print(str(a) + ' is what you entered.')

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
```

`loader.py` imports that function and that class and defines a function to print their source code:

```
import inspect

from resources import resources

def testfunc():
    source_Bar = inspect.getsource(resources.Bar)
    print(source_Bar)

    source_foo = inspect.getsource(resources.foo)
    print(source_foo)
```

and `experiment.py` loads that printing function from `loader.py` and calls it:

```
from loader.loader import testfunc

testfunc()
```

I can run `experiment.py` in a Python console and get the expected output (source code for `foo` and `Bar`).

I then use PyInstaller to create an executable from `experiment.py` (from a virtual environment with just PyInstaller added).  The `spec` file is untouched (I can share it), but I do copy/paste the `loader` and `resources` directories to `dist/experiment` so that the executable can find them.  If I run `experiment.exe` from the Command Prompt, I get this output:

```
C:\Users\earne\Desktop\experiment\dist\experiment>experiment.exe
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiment\experiment.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "experiment\loader\loader.py", line 9, in testfunc
  File "inspect.py", line 973, in getsource
  File "inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
  File "inspect.py", line 786, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code
[14188] Failed to execute script experiment
```

**So the code for `Bar` is found and printed, but the code for `foo` cannot be found**!  Note that line 9 is where `foo` is inspected.

The real context is a graphing program where I want to return the code used to make a plot, in case users want to make tweaks.  So `foo` is actually a lot of `matplotlib` code, `loader` is a module for formatting the plot code, and `experiment` is the `tkinter` application.  As in this case, the `inspect` works fine from an IDE but breaks after building the exe.

More about my setup:

- the virtualenv was created with Anaconda Prompt; I used `conda create` to make a new environment and then `pip` installed PyInstaller
- Python is 3.7.7
- everything in the environment, basically what it comes with:

```
altgraph       0.17
certifi        2020.4.5.1
future         0.18.2
pefile         2019.4.18
pip            20.0.2
pyinstaller    4.0.dev0+03d42a2a25
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0
setuptools     46.1.3.post20200330
wheel          0.34.2
wincertstore   0.2
```

- Windows 10 64bit

What I've tried:

- a lot of switching the import method (e.g. explicitly importing the
  function by name, using import *, importing only the module and using
  module.function)
- messing around with the `.spec` file, like adding my modules to the `datas` argument of `Analysis`.
  I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1945), and I've tried to add my modules to `a.pure` as htgoebel commented, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, and it seems like maybe not the root issue since the code for the class `Bar` can be found from the same file
- I've used both the most current PyInstaller version (3.6) and the current developer version from `https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

Overall the weirdest part seems that **the class source code can be found but the function cannot**, when they are in the same file - but maybe PyInstaller is making it more complicated than that in a way I don't understand?  Please let me know if you have any suggestions or want me to try anything else.  Happy to provide any other information/tests that I can.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I've got a solution after doing a little more poking around - feels not ideal though.

To `loader` I added statements to print the module and file of both `foo` and `Bar` (the "`mymod`" is unnecessary):

```
import inspect
from resources import resources as mymod

def testfunc():
    print(inspect.getfile(mymod.Bar))
    print(inspect.getmodule(mymod.Bar))
    source_Bar = inspect.getsource(mymod.Bar)
    print(source_Bar)

    print(inspect.getfile(mymod.foo))
    print(inspect.getmodule(mymod.foo))
    source_foo = inspect.getsource(mymod.foo)
    print(source_foo)
```

Creating the program again, the output of `experiment.exe` points to the discrepancy between `foo` and `Bar`.   The print statements for `mymod.Bar` are:

```
C:\Users\...\dist\experiment\resources\resources.pyc
<module 'resources.resources' from 'C:\\Users\...\dist\\experiment\\resources\\resources.pyc'>
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
```

and for `mymod.foo`:

```
experiment\resources\resources.py
<module 'resources.resources' from 'C:\\Users\...\dist\\experiment\\resources\\resources.pyc'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
... #same error as before
```

So it seems that Python can recognize that they are from the same module, but not the actual file; there's an absolute path pointing to the `.pyc` file for `Bar`, while only a relative path to the `.py` file for `foo`.

So I tried to change the imports/be more explicit, and got to using `importlib`:

```
from importlib import import_module
mymod = import_module('resources.resources')
```

This fixed `experiment.exe` to give the right output:

```
C:\Users\...\dist\experiment\resources\resources.py
<module 'resources.resources' from 'C:\\Users\...\dist\\experiment\\resources\\resources.py'>
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

C:\Users\...\experiment\resources\resources.py
<module 'resources.resources' from 'C:\\Users\...\dist\\experiment\\resources\\resources.py'>
def foo(a):
    print(str(a) + ' is what you entered.')
```

So even for this, I don't understand why changing the import is needed.  Moreover, this fix didn't work in the context of my GUI - I still couldn't get the function source code but the class continued to work.  I ended up having to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) and do:

```
import importlib.util
homedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)
resources_dir = os.path.join(homedir, 'resources/resources.py')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("resources.resources", resources_dir)
mymod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(mymod)
#I do os stuff to get a relative path to resources from loader
```

And this works in the application - seems overly verbose and confusing, but ultimately it doesn't apparently affect the functioning of the application, either as an `.exe` or as a Python script.

Would still love to know what is going on here, if anyone feels like giving a shout.  Hope this helps someone if not.